# Extracting data from string for query?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am attempting to identify utility poles that require inspection. Currently, the feature has a field containing the pole's birthmark in a string format and an installation date field (with the majority being null values at the moment). The birthmark field is formatted as 40-5-18 where 40 is the height, 5 is the class, and 18 is the year. I need a Python solution to capture the last two digits of the birth mark string and either update the installation date field to some arbitrary date in the corresponding year or select values (< or > a particular year) using a mathematical operator. The ultimate goal is to be able to query poles due for inspection based on the date of the birthmark or installation.

Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! As a new user please take a moment to take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com) to learn about our focused Q&A format. Please note that this question is likely to be closed if you don't include a code snippet of what you've tried already, since you are asking for python-based solution. Please edit your question to include that code. If you haven't tried code yet, have you tried to do this within something like the Field Calculator in ArcGIS? (And what version of ArcMap / ArcGIS Pro are you using?)

Comment: I am not familiar enough with the syntax to attempt this without direction. I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.

Comment: One thing to do whenever you are trying to determine the arcpy syntax is first to identify the tools you would use interactively. One advantage to using ArcGIS Pro is that once you run the tool, you can right click on the output and copy the code. Interactively, I would start with creating a field to store the last two digits (installation year). The reason I'd do this rather than update the installation date field is simply for error checking. Then I'd use Field Calculator (syntax of `!birthmark![-2:]` should get the last two characters in the birthmark field, assuming it is string.)

Comment: Once you have worked out the details of how to approach it using interactive tools, you can convert this to arcpy.  (Right click the results from Field Calculator and copy the code, or look at the code snippets in the documentation: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm)

Comment: How would I convert it from string to integer so that the boolean operators will work when performing a selection query?

Comment: To clarify your original question -- is this something you will need to generate more than once or across multiple feature classes? If not, I would propose just using the Field Calculator rather than an arcpy solution.

Comment: Hopefully this is a one time scenario.

Comment: To convert a string (assuming it's digits only) to integer, you can use `int(fieldname)`. As a one-liner, it would be `int( !birthmark![-2:])`. Do you care about including the leading 19 or 20 (e.g. 2018, 1999) in the new field?

Comment: No, but maintaining the 0 in a year like 2004 so that it shows up as 04 would be helpful.

Comment: Greater-than and less-than are not boolean operators, they are mathematical operators. You don't need python for this, just use field calculator and extract the rightmost 2 characters.

Comment: @smiller those leading numbers actually might be needed. If I make a selection for < 10 I won't pick up the poles older than the year 2000.

Comment: What is the oldest year in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this solution only needs to be performed once and not repeated over a number of shapefiles, a Field Calculator based solution in ArcGIS Pro should work.

Because we want to add the leading 19 or 20 (to produce years such as 1999 or 2004), we need a slightly more complicated Field Calculator expression. You can create a function within a code block, and then pass the column to that function within the Field Calculator. Note the variable names within the codeblock won't have the surrounding exclamation marks that you will see in the field names for the field calculator.

I assumed that the earliest date is about 100 years ago 1919, so this will have to be modified to figure out the correct year if that's not the case.

Note that numbers with leading zeroes are considered octal in Python and you get unexpected results from converting using 'int'. I've included a workaround.

codeblock:

```
def extractyear(hgtclassyr):
    yrroot = hgtclassyr.split('-')[-1]  # split on dashes and take the last one
    yrroot = yrroot.rjust(2,'0') # adds 0 padding to two characters
    if yrroot.startswith('0'): 
        year = int('20' + yrroot) # converts to integer e.g. 2004, 2009
    elif int(yrroot) > 18:
        year = int('19' + yrroot) # converts to integer e.g. 1956
    else:
        year = int('20' + yrroot) # e.g. 2018
    return year
```

In the Field Calculator window, enter the codeblock as above and for the expression, enter

```
extractyear(!birthmark!)
```

For your additional question, if you wanted to return a date instead of an integer-valued year:

```
import datetime
def extractyear(hgtclassyr):
    yrroot = hgtclassyr.split('-')[-1]  # split on dashes and take the last one
    yrroot = yrroot.rjust(2,'0') # adds 0 padding to two characters
    if yrroot.startswith('0'): 
        year = '20' + yrroot # e.g. 2004, 2009
    elif int(yrroot) > 18:
        year = '19' + yrroot # e.g. 1956
    else:
        year = '20' + yrroot # e.g. 2018
    dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(year, '%Y')  #defaults to January 1st of the year.
    return dt_obj
```

Comment: I ran into the issue with octal number interpretation in Python2, but can't replicate today. (This workaround may not be necessary.)

Comment: ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 8, in extractyear
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20-4'

Comment: So in this case the entry was something like 40-5-4 instead of 40-5-04. Let's use split instead (by '-') to avoid these cases, and add in length checking.

Comment: used zero padding instead of length checking. Code in edited answer above.

Comment: Same error. Is there a way for the code to skip the features that aren't in like formatting and finish running?

Comment: What was the input for this particular line? if you are in an interactive view it should be the first one that has <null> as the result.

Comment: I didn't see a return value on my edit, so edited to include that.

Comment: It looks to be working now. Thank you for your input! If you don't mind, could you clarify exactly what is happening in lines 2 and 3 before the if statement?

Comment: Line 2: Split is an operation that works on strings. I've chosen to split on the dashes, so it would return a list of length 3: `["40", "5", "18"]`. We only need the final entry, so we use an index of `-1` (1st item on the right = last item). Line 3: If the value returned is a string with only a single character e.g. 1-9, pad it with a zero. `4` becomes `04`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Is it possible to now take that 4 digit year and convert it to date format? It can be a default mo/day.

Comment: Yes. I'll start you with these resources: a) the answer below. b) https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/ c) the datetime module. Please review these and post a new question with your code attempts if needed as it's really hard to do proper code formatting in comments, and we want to only have one question per post.  Each of these are on newlines: `import datetime \n yr = '2018' \n date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(yr, '%Y') \n print str(date_time_obj)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datetime module and update the date field with values from the text field:

```
import arcpy
from datetime import datetime

fc = 'Formulas' #Change
stringfield = 'birthmark' #Change
datefield = 'instdate' #Change

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,[stringfield,datefield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1]=datetime.strptime(row[0].split('-')[-1],'%y')
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, if your years are all between 1950 and 2049, you can use this one-line shortcut directly in the field calculator in python mode:

`2000 + int(!BirthMark![-2:]) - (int(!BirthMark![-2:])/50) * 100`

However, this would not work for years before 1950.

Comment: This produced some issues. As an example, an 04 pole returned as 1996.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, the destination field needs to be of type integer

Comment: After checking other comments I realized that the issue might be the fact that you have some values with missing trailing zero, like this : 40-5-4, so that's why. The last 2 characters must have been '-4', leading to a negative number. In this case, I think you'd better use smiller's solution.

Comment: A couple of changes will make this overall approach work with ArcGIS Pro (Python 3): 1) Use Split instead of string slicing, 2) use floor divisor instead of regular divisor.  `2000 + int(!BirthMark!.split('-')[-1]) - (int(!BirthMark!.split('-')[-1])//50) * 100`